# Android Sqllite not updating the column at all

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to update the column,i am able to add properly but I am not able to update.

Here is my code for updating.

```
public void setStatus(boolean status,int id,Context c){
        InitilizeSqlite(c);
        SQLiteDatabase db=userHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Table_Name,new String[]{
                        ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Id,
                        ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Date,
                        ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Time,
                        ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Medicine,
                        ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Reminder_Status}
        ,ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Id+ "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        int getId=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
        String date=cursor.getString(1);
        String time=cursor.getString(2);
        String medicine=cursor.getString(3);
        getstatus=Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(4));

        SQLiteDatabase dbUpdate=userHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Id,getId);
        values.put(ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Date,date);
        values.put(ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Time,time);
        values.put(ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Medicine,medicine);
        values.put(ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Reminder_Status,status);

        dbUpdate.update(ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Table_Name,values,ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Id+ "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    }
```

//Here is my column Detail

```
public class ReminderDetails {

    public static abstract class ReminderItem{
        public static final String Id="item_id";
        public static final String Time="time";
        public static final String Date="date";
        public static final String Medicine="medicine";
        public static final String Table_Name="reminder_details";
        public static final String Reminder_Status="reminder_status";
    }
}
```

Can any one help to me address what is the issue why am not able to update reminder status ?

Comment: Are you getting any `Exception`? Why do you update your `item_id` with the `ContentValues`? Have you check (with breakpoints or logs) that the data retrieved by the first cursor (id, date, time, medicine & status) is correct?

Comment: I removed the item_id from content value and getting return 1 of dbupdate.update operation there is no exception am getting. But still fields not updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution actually   values.put(ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Reminder_Status,status) here I was passing status in boolean but in my table I saved string so I just change to values.put(ReminderDetails.ReminderItem.Reminder_Status,"true") then its working fine. Thank you all who give time for this question.